# animationDidStop in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm generating `CALayer` when user taps the screen. Then I'm translating that layer to certain position using `Animation`. Then I'm removing it using this code in `animationDidStop`:

```
 [mylayer removeFromSuperLayer];
```

Here everything is working fine, but when I tap again before the previous animation stops, my current layer is not removed from the superlayer. How do I removed it under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new layer each time, then the delegate method will only be able to remove the current one (i.e. the older one will be lost)

You could try using `CATransaction begin/commit` pairs around your animations and adding completion block, this way you can pass the layers reference for each animation

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [myLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}];

//your existing animation code

[CATransaction commit];
```